# Android Face unlock option not showing in KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()

Tags: android, keyguard

I have used **keyguard manager** unlock page to open my application. Currently, I have used following `implicit intent` to launch android unlock page.

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

Intent i = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("title", "description");

startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
```

In unlock page it is showing only following two options

1. Pattern/Pin
2. Fingerprint

How to add face unlock too?

Comment: Okay @Zoe. Thanks for the information.